# Vue defineEmits: how to give function argument the type of an emit value

Tags: typescript, vuejs3

If I have defined emits:

```
const emits = defineEmits(['click-button', 'toggle-menu']);
```

Then I have a function which handles a click and takes a value which is the string that is going to be emitted:

```
const onClick = async (emitString: string | false = false) => {
  if (emitString) {
    emits(emitString);
  }
```

There is a typescript error on `if (emitString)`  that says: `Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type '"click-button" | "toggle-menu"'`.

So emitString needs to be typed as the union of the array values in defineEmits.
How can I get such a type?
I tried to change defineEmits and use a variable but it isn't possible to use local variables together with defineEmits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are asking for [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types):

```
const onClick = async (emitString: "click-button" | "toggle-menu" | false = false)
```

You can also extract it from the `emits`, using the [Parameters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterstype) utility type:

```
const onClick = async (emitString: Parameters<typeof emits>[0] | false = false)
```

[playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#eNqtkk1vwjAMhv+KlUuHxNg0bgyQNsRhO2xo7EY4dMXtAmkSJS4DAf99biu+JsRpUqXGX28e29mIJ+daywJFR3RD4pUjCEiFAx2brCcFBSn60qjcWU+wAY8p7CD1NoeIyyJppEmsCQSYKwrQgxmmyuCwtG4mUaJVsrj9KoisiZoQkc0yjbc5miKaNh6P5dYMylQWiMPaJHBT6o3JK5N14FwGtmcysIU01gG5tPo3oNeHjTQAKj2VadROqElPA4wBsJOGvz84D5d5RrGPcyT0oUtrhzatNfuT++m/0nTv6p3wBtggzJ2OCdnq3h0M0eQlMXSqstY8WMObrJSlSGzulEb/7khxU1J09ndKEWttf14rH/kCm3t/8o3J4oJ/HlalT4qRx4B+iVIcYhT7DKkOD8dvuOLzIZjbWaE5+0rwA4PVRclYpz0XZsbYJ3kV7Uv1BnlCn2G4IjRh31QJWs2sypeC3+XgSutH3HarvZ+12P0ClWEG9A==)